# Connection to MongoDB from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mongodb-java, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I want to create a connection to my database in MongoDB from Matlab R2015a. I have tried with both the drivers for C# and Java but none of them seem to work and I don't know what the problem is.

**For Java:

Code:**

```
javaaddpath('/%path%/mongodb-driver-3.0.0.jar')   
import com.mongodb.*;  
mongoClient = MongoClient();   
db = mongoClient.getDB('myDB');   
colls = db.getCollectionNames();   
coll = db.getCollection('myCollection');
```

**Error:**
No appropriate method, property, or field 'getDB' for class 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient'.

**For C#:

Code:**

```
NET.addAssembly('%path%\CSharpDriver-2.0.0\MongoDB.Driver.dll');  
import MongoDB.Driver.*;   
mongoClient = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient();  
mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();  
db = mongoClient.GetDatabase('myDB');  
collection = db.GetCollection('myCollection');
```

**Errors:**
1. No appropriate method, property, or field 'GetServer' for class 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient'.
2. If I comment the GetServer line I get: No appropriate method, property, or field 'GetCollection' for class 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl'.

I don't know if I am missing something and it would be really helpful if I could make it work.

I have also tried with the driver for Matlab but I couldn't make it create the .dll.
Thanks.

Comment: you error says that cant find the method getDB, make sure that you are importing the class properly

Comment: I don't know how to import it in other way besides what I wrote above...everywhere it is like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the client with:

```
import com.mongodb.*;  
mongoClient = MongoClient('myIP', 'myPort');
```

I'm using the java version with Matlab 2015b. I assume you have done the import correct. Otherwise, the `MongoClient` class would not be found.